# AndEngine camera offset and 2 scenes

Tags: android, andengine

I am using this method in Andengine to scroll through a list of items, by setting the camera's offset.

```
@Override
        public void onScroll(ScrollDetector pScollDetector, int pPointerID,
                float pDistanceX, float pDistanceY) {
            //Disable the menu arrows left and right (15px padding)
            if(mCamera.getXMin()<=15)
                menuleft.setVisible(false);
             else
                menuleft.setVisible(true);

             if(mCamera.getXMin()>mMaxX-15)
                 menuright.setVisible(false);
             else
                 menuright.setVisible(true);

            //Return if ends are reached
            if ( ((mCurrentX - pDistanceX) < mMinX)  ){                 
                return;
            }else if((mCurrentX - pDistanceX) > mMaxX){

                return;
            }

            //Center camera to the current point
            this.mCamera.offsetCenter(-pDistanceX,0 );
            mCurrentX -= pDistanceX;


            //Set the scrollbar with the camera
            float tempX =mCamera.getCenterX()-CAMERA_WIDTH/2;
            // add the % part to the position
            tempX+= (tempX/(mMaxX+CAMERA_WIDTH))*CAMERA_WIDTH;      
            //set the position
            //scrollBar.setPosition(tempX, scrollBar.getY());

            //set the arrows for left and right
            menuright.setPosition(mCamera.getCenterX()+CAMERA_WIDTH/2-menuright.getWidth(),menuright.getY());
            menuleft.setPosition(mCamera.getCenterX()-CAMERA_WIDTH/2,menuleft.getY());



            //Because Camera can have negativ X values, so set to 0
            if(this.mCamera.getXMin()<0){
                this.mCamera.offsetCenter(0,0);
                mCurrentX=0;
            }


        }
```

the problem is that i use this as my second scene in the Activity,
So when i navigate back to the first activity the first scene is out of position because of the camera being moved.

Is there anyway i can reset the camera when going back to the first scene?

I tried  Camer.reset() to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `mCamera.setCenter(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2);`. It will reset the camera position.

By the way, I see you keep changing the menu arrows according to the camera position. You know, AndEngine has a class to handle this case :) You have no reason to do it manually...
It's called `HUD`, which means [Head-Up Display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-up_display). You can extend the [HUD class](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/engine/camera/hud/HUD.java?r=8b167777ed16919fa2d504c797cba7ab20f4e5e1), a HUD is just a scene which is placed in a constant position on the screen. You can add as many entities to it as you want. Then, just call `mCamera.setHUD(Your HUD object here);` and you are done, no need to mess around with moving entities across the camera.

Another issue I see is, you call `mCamera.offsetCenter(0, 0);`. `offsetCenter` simply adds the parameters to the current center coordinates. Adding `0` has *no* influence at all, so this call is useless. What are you trying to achieve? Reset the camera back to (0, 0)?

**EDIT:**

Here is a HUD example from my own game:

```
public class AttackControl extends HUD {
// ===========================================================
// Constants          
// ===========================================================

// ===========================================================          
// Fields         
// =========================================================== 
private Sprite mSprite;
private IAttackControlClickListener mListener;
// ===========================================================          
// Constructors          
// =========================================================== 
public AttackControl(final float pX, final float pY, final Camera pCamera, final TextureRegion pTextureRegion, final IAttackControlClickListener pListener) {
    super.setCamera(pCamera);
    this.mListener = pListener;
    this.mSprite = new Sprite(pX, pY, pTextureRegion) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pTouchEvent, final float pX, final float pY) {
            AttackControl.this.mListener.onClick();
            return true;
        }
    };
    super.attachChild(this.mSprite);
    super.registerTouchArea(this.mSprite);
}
// ===========================================================          
// Getter & Setter          
// =========================================================== 

// ===========================================================          
// Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces          
// ===========================================================  

// ===========================================================          
// Methods          
// ===========================================================  

// ===========================================================          
// Inner and Anonymous Classes          
// ===========================================================  
public interface IAttackControlClickListener {
    public void onClick();
}
}
```

Then you create an instance of this class:

```
final AttackControl attackControl = new AttackControl(...);
```

and set it as the camera's HUD:

```
mCamera.setHUD(attackControl);
```

In any case you want to use more than 1 HUD, you set 1 as a HUD then make the next one be the first one's child scene. For example, If I have another HUD called `DisplayStats` and I have created it this way:

```
final DisplayStats displayStats = new DisplayStats(...);
```

Then, just set it as the attack control's child scene. Remember - *a HUD is scene!* All scene operations are legal here.

```
attackControl.setChildScene(displayStats);
```

And now, the next HUD could be the child scene of `displayStats`... And so on.

Comment: Thanks again jong. I am using an example i got from here http://www.andengine.org/forums/post25398.html?hilit=MenuItems#p25398 also how would the code look for HUD. This is my first time using it

Comment: I'll make you an example later, I have to go now. About the camera, try `mCamera.setCenter(CAMERA_WIDTH/2, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2);` If this doesn't work, just save the camera position when leaving the first scene, so you can switch back to it later.

Comment: mCamera.setCenter(CAMERA_WIDTH/2, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2); works like a charm

Comment: Great :) Do you still want a HUD example?

Comment: Yes please. That would be GREAT!

Comment: Jong, so I have a question.  Say I had 2 buttons, a fire and a reload button.  Would I create 2 seperate HUDs, one for each button?  

Or is it better to have one HUD with both buttons, and maybe even the OnScreenControls?  Design-Wise.

Comment: In the game I took this HUD code from, I have a move control and an attack control (This code). These are 2 different HUDs, because each one acts differently (One is just being clicked, another is being moved around.) so creating 2 different HUDs is a must. Design-wise, I still think each control should be in it's own class, so 2 HUDs.

Comment: Is there any reason why `mCamera.setCenter(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2);` wouldn't work for me? I'm doing this right after setting a new scene and my camera is still off. This is when using a ZoomCamera.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this in the future and the other answers do not suffice, try this.

```
 mCamera.setZoomFactor(1.0f);
```

This is necessary if you are using a `ZoomCamera`. I was doing this and so if I "pinched to zoom" and then switched scenes, it was all messed up because my zoom factor was getting adjusted.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is totally necessary and worked for me.